# Deriving $\mathrm d\omega/\mathrm dk = v$

Tags: waves, dispersion, matter

I am reading Matter and Light by de Broglie and a little bit confused about how he deduced the equation of

$v_g := \frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dk} = v$

I understand that a wave that is static in one inertial frame could be written as

$ \phi=e^{2\pi i \nu_0 (t-\tau_0)}$

and if you see this wave from moving frame of reference (that moves $v$ to $-x$)

$ \phi=e^{2\pi i \nu_0 \left(\frac{{t^\prime-vx^\prime/c^2}}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} -\tau_0\right)}$

this way you get

$\nu = \frac{\nu_0}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$

and

$ \lambda = \left ( \frac{\nu_0 v}{c^2 \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} \right )^{-1}$

and you could calculate $\frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dk}$ using the facts that $\omega = 2\pi \nu$ and $ k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ and the chain rule

$ \frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dk} = \frac{\frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dv}}{\frac{\mathrm dk}{\mathrm dv}}$

and get the answer

$ \frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dk} = v$

but I don't understand the last part.
what is the physical meaning of applying chain rule below.

$\large \frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dk} = \frac{\frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dv}}{\frac{\mathrm dk}{\mathrm dv}}$

I am confused because we are looking at the electron from one frame of reference and $v$ is constant. Constant means not changing. For example if we use chain rule by $ \nu_0$ we get something like this.

$\large \frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dk} = \frac{\frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm d\nu_0}}{\frac{\mathrm dk}{\mathrm d\nu_0}}$

and we get different result

$\large \frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dk} = \frac{c^2}{v}$

I wonder the difference between them.

Comment: I edited the equations to try and make them look nicer. However, I cannot be sure if all the $\nu$ and $v$ are translated correctly. Please check that. It is impossible to check if your $v_g=\mathrm d\omega/\mathrm dk$ is computed correctly because you did not include the actual result; only $c^2/v$ from differentiating by $\nu_0$ is check-able.

Comment: Thank you for making them look nicer.I checked and corrected. Derivation is on this video => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIyE1IqbIEI

Comment: Related :  [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is  E? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207). Note that $\:c^2/\upsilon\:$ is the velocity of the "superluminal" phase wave.

Comment: Related :  [Which of the following two formulas is the correct wavelength expression of a relativistic electron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/612836/which-of-the-following-two-formulas-is-the-correct-wavelength-expression-of-a-re/612892#612892).

Comment: @Frobenius  Your posts are awesome. I am trying to learn from your posts. Thank you so much.